# Change someone to do something

Tags: writing

Is it natural to say "change someone to do something instead of something"?

For example, I would like to say

"I changed my program to use linear layer instead of convolution layer".

In this sentence "my program" is the subject of "to use". So I am not using "to use" as a purpose. My program is actually something using 'linear layer'.

Comment: You could definitely rephrase it so it's clearer. Personally, I think your sentence is technically correct. But, I'm not a native English speaker, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: It needs to be either (1) ***a*** *linear layer* or (2) *linear* ***layers***. The same is true of the second noun. Either insert an indefinite article, or make it plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the sentence is clear, unambiguous and concise. You changed the program to do ... what? To use one procedure instead of another. A similar example is “We altered our heating system to use oil rather than coal”. “Oil rather than coal” seems to me to be a noun phrase that is the object of the verb “use”.

There are alternatives that may be a little clearer but are longer. For example: “I altered my program so that it would use A instead of using B.”

Comment: “We altered our heating system to use oil rather than coal”. This types of saying is exactly what I was looking for. I was worried that if it is natural in English. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Note my comment under the question. The sentence, as written, is ungrammatical.